# DotNetCore Docker container could not connect to mssql

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

I have containerized our DotNetCore application.
Our application code connects to different SQL Server instances
We are observing a weird error that our Application is not able to connect to a particular SQL Server instance.

Any connection trying to hit the SQL will go forever in Sending form.

I tried the below to identify the error.

Debug my Docker container locally and install SQL CMD to check if I am able to connect to SQL Server
Below is the error that is occurring

```
root@aabcd:/app# sqlcmd -S abcinstnacename,3431  -U username -p -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
Password:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

SQL Server Version that is causing the error

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2-GDR) (KB4458621) - 13.0.5201.2 (X64)
```

In Docker file below are the base images I am using, will that cause any issue ?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
```

Also tried adding below line in my Dockerfile with no luck!

```
RUN sed -i '/^ssl_conf = ssl_sect$/s/^/#/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: Have you read/found that post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347344/0x2746-error-msodbcsql-connection-to-sql-server-2016

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did not see that post. The OpenSSL Version I have is OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019. I believe this is the latest.  Should I try with OpenSSL 1.0 ?  If Yes could you point me to few references on how to have that installed using Dockerfile

Comment: Have you checked the TLS 1.2 support of your server? I know Ubuntu 20.04 and above needs some workarounds to connect to sql server below 2017, not sure about debian though

Comment: Downgrading to OpenSSL 1.0 by adding below line in Dockerfile resolved the issue   RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf